# NETSTANDARD error Build action 'EmbeddedResource' is not supported by one or more of the project's targets

Tags: xamarin.forms, embedded-resource, portable-class-library, .net-standard

We migrate our project to NET STANDARD, but when the project is compiled many errors appear on the errors list:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Build action 'EmbeddedResource' is not supported by one or more of the project's targets.   MyApp   C:\desenvolvimento\aplicativo\App\MyApp\App.xaml    0

the project runs normally but many of this errors appears...

i am using the latest version of Visual Studio 2015 and Xamarin, all the libs and softwares are up to date.

Comment: are you getting these errors on XAML files?

Comment: Yes @Rohit these errors are on XAML Files

Comment: Its a weird thing with the Xamarin Forms, you will have to create new XAML pages and copy paste everything. I have not found a way around yet. The same thing happens if you add XAML by "Add Existing Item". You can ignore this as it is pretty harmless.

Comment: @Rohit i tried to delete the xaml file and create again, but this do not work...the errors appears yet.

Answer (score 3):

These are only Intellisense errors. If you just switch your error list filter to Build Only (instead of Build + Intellisense), then you will see that they disappear and your project will continue to build.

Comment: I have yet to find a way to remove the errors, but will post back if I ever do come across it. Googling the issue shows many ways other people have resolved it but never for a .NET Standard based proj.

Answer (score 1):

If your project is building correctly but these errors persist, this is because Visual Studio keeps a cache of the errors on `.suo` (Solution User Options) and sometimes these errors are not refreshed as should.

To force refresh close Visual Studio and delete all `.suo` files (including inside `.vs` folder). You will loose all state for this project (open files and windows, windows positions etc).

Comment: You should provide more detailed explanation of what you propose and why you think it may help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and searched online, eventually found this answer https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/89268/#Comment_89268

It looks like a tag in the older VS solution file is the cause.
As stated in the answer, you can fix the build error by opening up the .csproj file in a text editor, finding the EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports Target and removing it.

```
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
        <PropertyGroup>
              <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
        </PropertyGroup>
        <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.1.2.2.6243\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10\Xamarin.Forms.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)','..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.1.2.2.6243\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10\Xamarin.Forms.targets'))" />
  </Target>
```

Loaded solution and all working.